# Google Scripts IF statement with column number

Tags: google-apps-script

new to Google Scripts and seem to be managing ok but ran into a problem..

I have a trigger 'on edit' which I want to run ONLY if the user edited a cell in column 3. With the code below it runs regardless of which column is edited. Hope someone can help. Thanks

```
 function sendNotification2() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
var row = ss.getActiveRange().getRow();
var column = ss.getActiveRange().getColumn();

 if(column = 3){ 
Browser.msgBox('you edited column 3!', Browser.Buttons.OK);
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace This:**

if(column=3)

This is an assignment

**With This:**

if(column==3)

**Upon further review I'd try this as well.**

```
function sendNotification2() 
{
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
 var row = cell.getRow();
 var column = cell.getColumn();
 if(column == 3)
 { 
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('column3.');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'You Edited')
 }
}
```

**Here's another way to go:**

```
function onEdit(e) 
{
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
 var row = cell.getRow();
 var column = cell.getColumn();
 if(column == 3)
 { 
  var s=Utilities.formatString('You edited column %s row %s oldvalue = %s newvalue = %s ', column, row, e.oldValue, e.value);
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Column 3 Edits')
 }
}
```

Comment: You might want to check the answer again.  I added a couple of things to the function and changed the name to onEdit() to use a simple trigger.

Comment: You could use the event parameter and cut down on some of the code. For instance, `var column = e.range.getColumn()` would return an integer you can test in the `if` statement.